Startup error "Cassandra 5.0 requires Java 11 or Java 17"
I can only find that Cassandra supports JDK17, and no Java flavor specifics. First I installed OpenJDK11 and received the same message as below.
I then found that Cassandra 5.0 only supports JDK17.  Fine, they should probably change the message if so but okay. I then installed OpenJDK17 and still received the below.
$ which java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

$ java -version
openjdk version "17-ea" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17-ea+11-Ubuntu-114.042)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17-ea+11-Ubuntu-114.042, mixed mode, sharing)

vm1@ubuntu:/opt/apache-cassandra-5.0.0/bin$ ./cassandra 
Cassandra 5.0 requires Java 11 or Java 17.

I then tried with Oracle Java 17, same. What gives?
$ which java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java

$ java -version
java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing)

vm1@ubuntu:/opt/apache-cassandra-5.0.0/bin$ ./cassandra 
Cassandra 5.0 requires Java 11 or Java 17.


So Cassandra determines your JVM version with this code in cassandra.in.sh:
# Determine the sort of JVM we'll be running on.
java_ver_output=`"${JAVA:-java}" -version 2>&1`
jvmver=`echo "$java_ver_output" | grep '[openjdk|java] version' | awk -F'"' 'NR==1 {print $2}' | cut -d\- -f1`
JVM_VERSION=${jvmver%_*}
short=$(echo "${jvmver}" | cut -c1-2)

JAVA_VERSION=17
if [ "$short" = "11" ]  ; then
     JAVA_VERSION=11
elif [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "17" ] ; then
    echo "Cassandra 5.0 requires Java 11 or Java 17."
    exit 1;
fi

When I force the java -version outputs that you have shown above, my variable for short is equal to 17. This should be fine.
However, above this code block is another which checks for the presence of a $JAVA_HOME env var. If that's set in your environment, it's what is used.
One thing you could try, would be to edit the error message in your local bin/cassandra.in.sh file to include the failing version number:
    echo "Cassandra 5.0 requires Java 11 or Java 17. ${JVM_VERSION} is not valid."

I'm curious to see what that would say.

I get this on my macOS
% java -version|grep '[openjdk|java] version' | awk -F'"' 'NR==1 {print $2}' | cut -d\- -f1 giving output as
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode) 

@Madhavan java -version sends its output to stderr instead of stdout. Since stdout is empty, nothing happens when you pipe it to commands like grep or awk. You need to redirect to stdout with java -version 2>&1 before you can pipe it to another command. Cheers!

Background
For a long time, Apache Cassandra only worked with Java 8. In 2015, work commenced on adding support for newer versions of Java, particularly Java 9 and 10. However, things changed in 2017 when Oracle announced a 6-month release cycle which ultimately meant that Java releases would reach EOL at a fast rate.
LTS support
As a result, the Cassandra community decided to only certify Java releases with long-term support (LTS). In C* 4.0, support for Java 11 LTS was added (CASSANDRA-9608, CASSANDRA-16894) so it worked with both Java 8 and 11.
Cassandra 5.0 added support for Java 17 LTS and dropped support for Java 8 (CASSANDRA-18255) which means that C* 5.0 works with both Java 11 and 17.
Your environment
From the above, I hope it's clear which versions of Java is supported and that the issue is with the VM you're running because the symptoms point to an underlying problem with the OS/shell environment.
I suspect you have multiple versions of Java installed and the system is confused as to which Java installation is configured.
When you run the bin/cassandra script to start Cassandra, it also runs the bin/cassandra.in.sh script (line 82) which then verifies the version of Java installed.
You need to debug the script to figure out why it's not working in your VM. First thing is to verify whether JAVA_HOME is (1) set in your shell profile, and (2) pointing to a Java installation you didn't expect.
If JAVA_HOME is not set then (3) run the following command to evaluate which Java installation is picked by the shell:
$ command -v java

If it's symlinked, (4) trace it all the way until you identify the installation.
If all else fails, debug the cassandra.in.sh and run the commands line-by-line particularly from line 99 until you identify the root cause. Cheers!
